# Redirect returning users to specific page

Tags: cookies, redirect, web

This questions is more conceptual that asking for actual code.

I want to redirect returning anonymous users to a page other than the home page. Is there any other way to do this than to use a cookie? Is a cookie an ok way of accomplishing this? I'm worried about the reliability of cookies, but maybe I'm mistaken in questioning that.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would say create a session state instead if your worried about cookie reliance.

You can make the session state last a bit longer than default.  Keep it as small as possible ie. a simple bool.

As long as the cookies stay on the same domain, they should be considered first-party cookies.
I think **it is safe to assume that a significant large majority of browsers only reject 3rd party cookies.**

Since security (it is on the client side and subject to attack) and filesize (cookies usually have a maximum size) do not seem to be an issue here, why not?

Comment: Am I misguided in thinking cookies are unreliable?

Comment: @jrubins Here is my revision.

Answer (score 0):

as you think about a security issue than it is better to use Session for this.
but if you want to use third-party cookie than take care of following points while setting up cookie.

- Use **persistant cookie** (set expire date of cookie).
- Create cookie with **HttpOny** parameter.
- if your server using Secure Connection (ie. **https**) than use
  **Secure Cookie**.